# Can't access this.state from React.Children.map()

Tags: reactjs, this, state, children

As the title says, I need to access each `child` element of the map function of all children, `React.Children.map(this.props.children, (child)...`

I need this because I want to conditionally render certain props, and also prevent rendering based on certain conditions depending on which child is being rendered at the moment.

I have bound this function in the constructor

```
this.renderChildren = this.renderChildren.bind(this);
```

but it's still not working. 
The only way I can even get this map function to work is if I wrap it in a `return()` function. Any ideas?

```
renderChildren(funcs) {
    // debugger
    return (
      React.Children.map(this.props.children, (child) => {
        debugger // *** Need to access `this.state` from in here ***
        return React.cloneElement(child, {
          state: this.state,    // ***  Need access here too
          callbackFuncs: funcs
        })
      })
    )
  }

...

return(<div>{this.renderChildren(callbacks)}</div>)
```

The following will NOT work (not wrapped in a return)

```
renderChildren(funcs) {
    React.Children.map(this.props.children, (child) => {
      return React.cloneElement(child, {
        state: this.state,    
        callbackFuncs: funcs  
      })
    })
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are correct, you need to wrap the `map` in a `return ( ... )` in your `renderChildren`.

When you do this `return(<div>{this.renderChildren(callbacks)}</div>)` if `renderChildren(callbacks)` is not returning anything then `{this.renderChildren(callbacks)}` will be empty.

To solve your problem instead of binding `this` in your constructor

Remove this line `this.renderChildren = this.renderChildren.bind(this);` in your constructor

Change

```
renderChildren(funcs) {
// debugger
return (
  React.Children.map(this.props.children, (child) => {
    debugger // *** Need to access `this.state` from in here ***
    return React.cloneElement(child, {
      state: this.state,    // ***  Need access here too
      callbackFuncs: funcs
    })
  })
)
}
```

to

```
renderChildren = (funcs) => {
// debugger
return (
  React.Children.map(this.props.children, (child) => {
    debugger // *** Need to access `this.state` from in here ***
    return React.cloneElement(child, {
      state: this.state,    // ***  Need access here too
      callbackFuncs: funcs
    })
  })
)
}
```

And then you can access `this` as you wish inside the closure

Comment: I initially had issues with the arrow function running, but added `transform-class-properties` to babel and it is running. However, I still cannot access `this.state`. I am so confused.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. First, had to add `transform-class-properties` to my `.babelrc` file with an npm install as well [here](https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/transform-class-properties/)

Then, I autobound it like suggested above with an arrow function, but I STILL could not access my state from inside of the `.map` function. I ended up finding this Github issue, [Here](https://github.com/react-bootstrap/react-bootstrap/issues/1729#issuecomment-203268407)

That said to bind the function with the second arg from the map function, which I did and not it works. Here is the revised version...

```
 renderChildren = (funcs) => {
    return (
      React.Children.map(this.props.children, (child) => {
        return React.cloneElement(child, {
          state: this.state, 
          callbackFuncs: funcs
        })
      }, this)
    )
  };
```